# How do I print a list from the data in my database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display a list of these points that are shown in the table.

```
folio_mainPoint_bulletPoint_table
idFolio   idMainPoint   idBulletPoint
8         13            14
8         13            15
8         14            16
8         15            17
8         15            18
8         15            19
```

these are the tables that I have:

```
folioTable 
idFolio folio
8       123

mainPointTable
idMainPoint mainPoint
13          Animals
13          Animals
14          Flowers
15          Insects
15          Insects
15          Insects

bulletPointTable
idBulletPoint bulletPoint
14            Dog
15            Cat
16            Rose
17            Ant
18            Grasshopper
19            Fly
20            ladybug
```

The output should be:

```
Folio 123

Animals
 1. Dog
 2. Cat

Flowers
 1. Rose

Insects
 1. Grasshopper
 2. Fly
 3. ladybug
```

I am stuck in this because I keep looping the data without being able to print out a list of only the data related to the folio with the idFolio of 8. This is the code that I have so far:

```
$sql = mysqli_query(" SELECT * FROM folio_mainPoint_bulletPoint_table where idFolio='8' ") or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $sql )) {

echo  $folio = $row['idFolio'];
$idBulletPoint = $row['idBulletPoint '];

$sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT bulletPoint FROM bulletPointTable where idBulletPoint ='$idBulletPoint' ");
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $sql2 )){

   }

}
```

Comment: You can do all this in single query using join

`SELECT * FROM folio_mainPoint_bulletPoint_table 

Inner Join bulletPointTable 

On bulletPointTable.idBulletPoint = folio_mainPoint_bulletPoint_table.idBulletPoint`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.. `mysql_fetch_assoc()`

```
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM folio_mainPoint_bulletPoint_table where idFolio='8'") or die(mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $sql )) {

    echo  $folio = $row['idFolio'];
    $idBulletPoint = $row['idBulletPoint '];
    $sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT bulletPoint FROM bulletPointTable where idBulletPoint ='$idBulletPoint' ");
       while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc( $sql2 )){
   echo $row['column_name'];
       }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

while($result= mysql_fetch_assoc( $sql )) {

print_r($result);

}